# Excel 2016 - Conditional Formatting an entire Row

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to add conditional formatting to an entire Row based on the corresponding entries on the values in the row below.

I need to set it up for the entire row as i am importing the data and the amount of columns taken up will be different on each import.[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3K0rD.png)

As you can see i want to change the cell reference where it says "P23?" to yellow if the words Cast appear in the Cell below.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change your formula to:

```
=A4="Cast"
```